`pandas.tseries.offsets` hard to predict result
I found it really hard to predict the results produced by pandas.tseries.offsets, especially when n==0. Below is an example with MonthEnd and MonthBegin.
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd, MonthBegin

date_ = pd.to_datetime('20240601')
print(date_ + MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-06-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-06-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-05-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-05-31 00:00:00
print('\n')

date_ = pd.to_datetime('20240615')
print(date_ + MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-06-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-05-31 00:00:00
print('\n')

date_ = pd.to_datetime('20240630')
print(date_ + MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(0))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-07-01 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthBegin(1))  # 2024-06-01 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(0))  # 2024-06-30 00:00:00
print(date_ + MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-07-31 00:00:00
print(date_ - MonthEnd(1))  # 2024-05-31 00:00:00

If I have to add an if MonthBegin().is_month_end(date_) else ... before? If there is a way can simplify the logic and make the results predictable? e.g.
for date_ in ['20240601','20240615','20240630']:
    # In a word, `n==0` indicates this month, `n==-1` means the previous month and `n==1` means the next month.
    date_= pd.to_datetime(date_)
    print(date_ + MonthBegin(0))  # == 2024-06-01 00:00:00
    print(date_ - MonthBegin(0))  # == 2024-06-01 00:00:00
    print(date_ + MonthBegin(1))  # == 2024-07-01 00:00:00
    print(date_ - MonthBegin(1))  # == 2024-05-01 00:00:00
    print(date_ + MonthEnd(0))  # == 2024-06-30 00:00:00
    print(date_ - MonthEnd(0))  # == 2024-06-30 00:00:00
    print(date_ + MonthEnd(1))  # == 2024-07-31 00:00:00
    print(date_ - MonthEnd(1))  # == 2024-05-31 00:00:00


As you could notice in your example, some combinations are stable.
Thus you can combine a subtraction and addition:
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    print(date_ + MonthBegin(1) - MonthBegin(1)) # 2024-06-01 00:00:00
    
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    print(date_ - MonthEnd(1) + MonthEnd(1)) # 2024-06-30 00:00:00

Adding several months:
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    n = 5
    print(date_ + MonthBegin(1+n) - MonthBegin(1)) # 2024-11-01 00:00:00
    
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    n = 5
    print(date_ - MonthEnd(1) + MonthEnd(1+n)) # 2024-11-30 00:00:00

Subtracting several months:
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    n = 5
    print(date_ + MonthBegin(1) - MonthBegin(1+n)) # 2024-01-01 00:00:00
    
for date_ in (pd.to_datetime('20240601'),
              pd.to_datetime('20240615'), 
              pd.to_datetime('20240630')):
    n = 5
    print(date_ - MonthEnd(1+n) + MonthEnd(1)) # 2024-01-30 00:00:00

